# Why does repaint() work correctly, but update() doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyqt5

I'm new in PyQt5, trying to study how it works. I created a window, put a button on it, connected click event to corresponding method. The code is simple - when button is pressed, the counter is being increased and new value needs to be shown in the center of the window. But if I use self.update() (as it's recommended in some sources) the window is being refreshed only when I resize or move it, not immediately after the button is pressed. And if I use self.repaint() everything works fine. Could you explain me the difference between these methods and why one of this works so strange?

```
class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'First Try'
        self.value = 1
        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startPressed)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 640, 480)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.startButton)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
        qp.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 30))
        qp.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, str(self.value))
        qp.end()

    def startPressed(self):
        self.value += 1
        self.update()
```

Comment: Doesn't update require the region being updated? As per the Qt5 Docs?

Comment: It works for me correctly in Linux with PyQt5 5.13, if the code you provide is the complete code then for me you have a bug, try PyQt5 updated and report the bug.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to update it. And yes, the code is complete. This code works, but if I use self.update in the end of this - it doesn't. Updated the code in the question.

Comment: @gurk 
It works for me with update() so I presume it is a bug, what is your OS? What version of python do you have, what version of PyQt5 do you have?

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you for answer. PyQt5 5.13.0 MacOS 10.14.5 Python 3.7

Comment: @gurk mmm, Mac OS, in these months I have seen several such bugs so the answer is: "bug", report it.